# Collections.sort() Synchronized

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a list and I need to sort it, in a thread-safe way, in Java. I need the return to be a list.

I wrote the code below but since `myListToOrder` is already a `synchronizedList` I am not sure the `Collections.sort(myListToOrder);` needs to be inside a `synchronized` block.

```
private  List<String> sortSynchronized(){
    List<String> myListToOrder = Collections.synchronizedList(this.myList);
            synchronized (myListToOrder) {
                Collections.sort(myListToOrder);
            }
return myListToOrder;
}
```

Note: `myList` is created as: `protected final List<String> myList = Lists.newArrayList();`

Any opinion on that?

Comment: Did you attempt making `this.myList` a "synchronized list"?

Comment: This is what I am doing with Collections.synchronizedList(this.myList), no? The problem is I don't know if after I need the sort inside synchronized (myListToOrder) {} or not. And could not find my answer by reading the JavaDoc :)

Comment: this.myList is an ArrayList(). I will adit on the post

Comment: Wrapping it with `Collections.synchronizedList` like that will do absolutely nothing since anything else accessing it in parallel will be accessing the underlying list, not the wrapped list. Read the javadoc of [`Collections.synchronizedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)).

Comment: Why the question was closed? Don't understand

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira: the close reason is given in the blue box above. For me it says "Closed. This question is opinion-based". Can you see that? If so, can you explain what you don't understand about that statement?

Comment: Sure, my question was "I am not sure the Collections.sort(myListToOrder); needs to be inside a synchronized block.". So this is a question with a defined answer, not an "opinion". I guess the phrase I put in the end "Any opinion on that?" was misleading, but this is not an opinion-based question

Answer (score 4):

You need to make sure that there is no access to the list while it is sorted (all accesses need to either "happen before" or "happen after" sorting).

In your case, you have a `List`, creating a `synchronized` *view* on the `List` and `synchronize` on that view. However, other code can still access the original list in the meantime.

You can fix this issue by using the same `synchronizedList` for all operations:

```java
private final List<String> myList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());

private List<String> sortSynchronized(){
    synchronized (myList) {//no other access to myList is possible during this block
        Collections.sort(myListToOrder);
    }
    return myListToOrder;
}
```

Alternatively, you can introduce your own synchronization strategy for that list and secure all access to the `List` that way, e.g. using `ReadWriteLock`.

However, it should be noted that other accesses to the `List` can mess up sorting right after `sortSyncronized` finishes. Instead of returning the same `List`, you might want to (sort and) return a copy:

```
private final List<String> myList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
private List<String> sortedCopy(){
    List<String> copy;
    synchronized(myList){//or however you want to secure access - elements being added to the list during copying might cause issues
        copy = new ArrayList<>(myList);
    }
    Collections.sort(copy);
    return copy;
    //or if you want to have a synchronizedList
    //return Collections.synchronizedList(copy); 
}
```

Comment: Got it! I would like to have a new instance sorted of my list and not Collection.sort() on the original myList because this have collateral effects. That's why I was creating a new synchronizedList from my list

Comment: On the second answer why Collections.sort(copy); is not inside    synchronized(myList){/} ?

Comment: Because you are operating on a copy - nothing can interfere with the copy as the copy is not published.

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira "_That's why I was creating a new synchronizedList from my list_" – Note that `synchronizedList` does **not** return a "new" list. It decorates the given list with a synchronized list. All actions on the synchronized **view** ultimately delegate to the given list.

Comment: D'Oh! I did not read the documentation for `Collections.synchronizedList(...)`. I did not realize that the returned `List` object uses itself as the synchronization object. Comment withdrawn.